# Delete system tmp file with COM and Word

Tags: php, com, ms-word, temp

I am using COM to convert dynamically created word docx to PDFs. Everything is working perfectly, but our  c:\windows\temp\ directory is getting extremely large (and we have limited disk space on our C drive). Below is the code I am using to generate the PDF. Is there a way to delete the temp file that gets added to the system's temp directory after the file is closed? In addition, after the word doc is converted to pdf, we no longer need it (so it doesn't matter if deleting the tmp file corrupts the word doc).

```
 /Word Doc to PDF using Com
ini_set("com.allow_dcom","true");

try{
    $word = new com('word.application');
}
catch (com_exception $e)
{
    $nl = "<br />";
    echo $e->getMessage() . $nl;
    echo $e->getCode() . $nl;
    echo $e->getTraceAsString();
    echo $e->getFile() . " LINE: " . $e->getLine();
    $word->Quit();
    $word = null;
    die;

}

$word->Visible = 0; //don't open word gui on server
$word->DisplayAlerts = 0; //don't allow any alerts to open 
//open doc
try{
    $doc = $word->Documents->Open(DOC_LOCATION . "temp_doc/" .  $filename . ".docx");
}
catch (com_exception $e)
{
    $nl = "<br />";
    echo $e->getMessage() . $nl;
    echo $e->getCode() . $nl;
    echo $e->getFile() . " LINE: " . $e->getLine();
    $word->Quit();
    $word = null;
    die;
}
try{
    $doc->ExportAsFixedFormat(DOC_LOCATION . "temp_pdf/" . $filename . ".pdf", 17, false, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, true, true, 2, true, true, false);

}
catch (com_exception $e)
{
    $nl = "<br />";
    echo $e->getMessage() . $nl;
    echo $e->getCode() . $nl;
    echo $e->getTraceAsString();
    echo $e->getFile() . " LINE: " . $e->getLine();
    $word->Quit();
    $word = null;
    die;
}
$word->Quit();
$word = null;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't say what version, but for XP- you can use a simple batch file to delete the files in **\Documents and Settings\USER\Local Settings\temp\**. Example:

```
C:
cd \Documents and Settings\USER\Local Settings\Temp
attrib -R -S -H *.* /S /D
DEL /S /F /Q *.*
```

Modify accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The IT manager wants it to delete the file as soon as we are finished with it, and we can't clear out the whole temp directory (apparently some session data gets stored in there)

Comment: But it seems you know the name of the temp files ($doc->ExportAsFixedFormat(DOC_LOCATION . "temp_pdf/" . $filename . ".pdf",...), for example. Why not just delete them with **unlink( 'TempFile")**;

Comment: Does the $doc->ExportAsFixedFormat() return the temp file name or something? If not, all that line does is creates the pdf in a directory we named temp_pdf (doesn't do anything with a tempfile. In your statement (unlink('TempFile'); don't you have to define 'TempFile' somehow?

Comment: Understood. It is a temporary file, but not the system one you want to delete.